# Best way to dissolve/emulsify beeswax and carnauba wax in water-based solution

Tags: experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solvents

What I can use to dissolve [beeswax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beeswax) and [carnauba wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnauba_wax) and keep it in an aqueous solution? I do not want to use ethanol or acetone as they are too harsh.

I am adding about $\pu{5\%}$ wax to a $\pu{16oz}$ aqueous solution that also has some oil in it. I need to stop it from coagulating and be fine enough or in solution to pass through the nozzle of a spray bottle without clogging it ?

Comment: Well, you'd need proper emulsifier and right mixing procedure.

Comment: Thanks Mithoron, how do I identify the emulsifier and establish the mixing procedure? Do you think vegetable oil might work ?

Comment: **No**, and I have a feeling that you need to learn a lot do it. One google search and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsifying_wax pops up. You should have tried searching before asking.

Comment: I stand corrected. No excuse for lazyness! I'm not a chemist or student simply trying to find a solution (excuse the pun) and thought this might be a good forum for that

Comment: Well, we can help you to some extent, but if you'd knew more before asking question could be better. This link may be useful and maybe someone working with cosmetics winds-up.. who knows.. It's not like we can do entire part of project for you  though ;)

Comment: As a polysorbate maybe SCATTICS Castor oil might work, heating the wax and oil which can then be added to water, thoughts?

Comment: Well, I guess you need to wait for an expert in this stuff...

Answer (score 2):

Try Oelic acid and TEA with Waxes.
1. Take 3% Oelic acid
2. Add 3% TEA in Oelic acid and stir it with continuous heating up to 50C.
3. Take 100ml Water in Above solution.
4. Take 20grm carnuaba wax and dissolve it in above solution with continuous mixing and heating up to 60C.
5. Again add 40 to 50ml water in above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need an emulsifier such as 1% [Tween 80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysorbate_80) and heat the wax with water to 65 °C with stirring, then let it cool down.
It will become a fat blur that dissolves in mixtures by agitating the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering what your use case was for. I'm doing a natural-ish waterless spray to clean your car with a quick spray solution. Beeswax and carnauba wax are both hydrophobic, meaning they are not soluble in water. To dissolve these waxes, you will need a solvent that is capable of dissolving them.

One option is to use a solvent like mineral spirits or turpentine. These solvents are commonly used to dissolve waxes and can be found at hardware stores or online.

Another option is to use a natural solvent such as citrus solvent or pine oil. These solvents are derived from natural sources and can be effective at dissolving waxes. However, they may have a strong smell and may be more expensive than synthetic solvents.

To make a waterless car wash spray with dissolved beeswax and carnauba wax, you will need to mix the dissolved waxes with other ingredients such as surfactants, lubricants, and water. It's important to note that the final product may not be completely aqueous due to the presence of the dissolved wax.

Carlos
caro1008@hotmail.com